# How Identity Managment can value add into single-sign-on system

Tags: single-sign-on, openam, opensso, identity-management

I want to know how Identity Management such OpenIDM can value add into single-sign-on e.g: OpenSSO / OpenAM System. I am searching the web for this but answers look complex to me. Can anyone please explain few points on how we could use OpenIDM beside OpenAM.

From what I can see for now is `OpenIDM` provides user / application interface for user registering (provisioning) process to supplement user credential creation in the OpenAm console. How about Workflow, governance and access ?  And not to limit to what I have mentioned, it will useful if you could point out some reference implementation or case study of both `openIDM` and `openAM` sit side by side to value add to Identity and Access Management.

I am sorry if the question does not suit stackoverflow I appreciate the patience of the readers. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on your requirements.  I need more info to help.

Comment: @tom , Please refer to updated question. Thx

Comment: You would get more traction by asking this question on the ForgeRock OpenIDM mailing list. https://lists.forgerock.org/mailman/listinfo/openidm

Comment: This question appears to be "what does openIDM do?" or "why would I use openIDM?".  The answer, unfortunately, is "it depends".